# Custom Application Menu in Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, menu

I manage to make Mac OS X Application Menu work on Java using com.apple.eawt API and added handlers for "About App", "Preferences..." and "Quit App" menu item.

But is it possible to add some custom menu option in this Application Menu in Java?

By example, Safari have "Report Bugs...", "Block Pop-Up", "Private Browsing...", etc. :

[image]

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

The [OSXAdapter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/OSXAdapter/Introduction/Intro.html) example application shows how to do this.

Addendum:

> it looks like it only defines `About/Preferences/Quit` handlers

Yes, `Services` and `Hide/Show` are supplied by the system. It sounds like you want to add menu items between `Preferences` and `Services`. Unfortunately, I've not tried that. You might look in [`com.apple.eawt`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/macosx/classes/com/apple/eawt) for alternatives. I can see it would be convenient; but for reference, NetBeans, Eclipse, *et al.* use the existing functionality.

Comment: Hum, sorry but it looks like it only define About/Preferences/Quit handlers after all... :(

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, now. I'm not sure how to do that. More above.

Comment: Thanks. com.apple.eawt does not offer anything more than these three handlers. I think my only chance is to work directly with the Cocoa framework throught JNI or Rococoa (Cyberduck seems to do this).